# How can I import "child" data into "parent" data table from a form access?

Tags: winforms, ms-access, vba

I work on tracking diseases for a public health org, and one of the complicated ones we deal with is Tuberculosis. I've developed an Access database with multiple forms and tabs to track any "Active TB case" (parent) to "Contacts" (child). The Active TB patient may have 20 or so contacts, but months down the line any one contact may become an Active TB case. The database tracks nearly 60 variables for the contact cases, but I want a few of these variables to be added into the parent table/form once they become an Active TB case.

I have two tables that will interface, one called Contact Info and the other Case Info.

**Contact Info** contains the following variables that will be added into the Case Info table: Contact#
Old#
MRN
Lastname
Firstname
Middlename
DOB
Sex

**Case Info** table contains: Case#
Old#
MRN
Last
First
Middle
DOB
Sex

You can see how the variables from Contact info should link with the corresponding variables in the Case Info table.

How can I have the "child" become the "parent"? I wanted to add a button on the child record that will do this.

Thanks in advance! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: In theory, all contacts should exist in one table, whether they're a child or a parent, otherwise you always have to worry about updating information in 2 separate tables.  Then, you have a Parent table (with a ContactID) and a Child table (with ParentID and associated Child ContactIDs).  All you'd have to do is create a button that simply adds a new record to the Parent table and puts the selected Child table's ContactID in that new record.

Answer (score 1):

Simply run an append query that filters on the specific patient which can be read from a form control (i.e., indicator on child form). Below assumes *MRN* as the criteria.

```sql
INSERT INTO [Case Info] ([Case#], [Old#], [MRN], [Last], [First], 
                         [Middle], [DOB], [Sex])
SELECT [Contact#], [Old#], [MRN], [Lastname], [Firstname], 
       [Middlename], [DOB], [Sex]
FROM [Contact Info]
WHERE [MRN] = Forms!myform!txtMRN
```

Append query can be a saved query and called behind form button with `DoCmd.OpenQuery` (same macro command) or run as action query in VBA with `DoCmd.RunSQL` or DAO's `CurrentDb.Execute` making sure the form value is concatenated to SQL string or better yet passed as parameter.